# Approximate matching

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R, and I have been wondering whether there exists a function or package for approximate (dateTime) matching. The function *intersect()* provides a list of exact matches, however I'm interested in an approximate match.

e.g. I have two arrays with dateTime values, and I want to have a list of occurences that occur in both arrays with a difference of max 2 seconds.

```
arrayA<-c("2000-12-31 10:00:00","2000-12-31 12:00:00")
arrayB<-c("2000-12-31 10:00:00","2000-12-31 12:00:01")
arrayA<-strptime(arrayA, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
arrayB<-strptime(arrayB, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

intersect(arrayA,arrayB) #returns "2000-12-31 10:00:00 UTC"
```

*intersect()* returns only the exact same values, but I'd like to return "2000-12-31 10:00:00 UTC" and "2000-12-31 12:00:00 UTC".

So basically my question is whether you can specify how well intersect matches occurences. My question concerns dates, but the same problem can be encountered with numeric values. My dataset is quite large, so 2 for-loops tend to take a long time for manually matching, and intersect is really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.table` package offers two approaches: The `foverlaps()` function and *non-equi joins*. Both approaches require to add helper columns to the data

#### Create Data

```
arrayA <- anytime::utctime(c("2000-12-31 10:00:00", "2000-12-31 12:00:00", 
                             "2000-12-31 12:00:05", "2000-12-31 12:00:10"), tz = "UTC")
arrayB <- anytime::utctime(c("2000-12-31 10:00:00", "2000-12-31 12:00:01", 
                             "2000-12-31 12:00:02", "2000-12-31 11:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
```

Note that both vectors are of class `POSIXct` which is more suitable than the `POSIXlt` class which is created by the `strptime()` function. In addition, more time stamps have been added to test non-matches.

#### Prepare data

The data preparation is the same for both approaches:

```
# make data.tables
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4 used here
A <- data.table(arrayA)
B <- data.table(arrayB)

# define tolerance = 2 * tol_half
tol_half <- 1L # seconds

# add helper columns
A[, "copyA" := arrayA]
A
#                arrayA               copyA
#1: 2000-12-31 10:00:00 2000-12-31 10:00:00
#2: 2000-12-31 12:00:00 2000-12-31 12:00:00
#3: 2000-12-31 12:00:05 2000-12-31 12:00:05
#4: 2000-12-31 12:00:10 2000-12-31 12:00:10

B[, `:=`(start = arrayB - tol_half, end = arrayB + tol_half)]
B
#                arrayB               start                 end
#1: 2000-12-31 10:00:00 2000-12-31 09:59:59 2000-12-31 10:00:01
#2: 2000-12-31 12:00:01 2000-12-31 12:00:00 2000-12-31 12:00:02
#3: 2000-12-31 12:00:02 2000-12-31 12:00:01 2000-12-31 12:00:03
#4: 2000-12-31 11:00:00 2000-12-31 10:59:59 2000-12-31 11:00:01
```

`start`and `end` in `B` denote the tolerable time range where `arrayA` must fit in to be considered a match. This is similar to what the `match_fun` function does on the fly in the [`fuzzyjoin` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43803492/3817004).

#### `foverlaps()`

With `foverlaps()` the overlapping time ranges in `A` and `B` are searched:

```
# setting keys is required by foverlap()
setkey(A, arrayA, copyA)
setkey(B, start, end)

# find overlaps
result <- foverlaps(B, A, nomatch = 0)[, c("copyA", "start", "end") := NULL][]
result
#                arrayA              arrayB
#1: 2000-12-31 10:00:00 2000-12-31 10:00:00
#2: 2000-12-31 12:00:00 2000-12-31 12:00:01
```

Note that `[, c("copyA", "start", "end") := NULL][]` immediatley removes the helper columns from the output of `foverlaps()`.

#### Non-equi joins

With the recent versions of `data.table`, *non-equi joins* are possible:

```
result <- A[B, .(arrayA, arrayB), on = c("copyA>=start", "copyA<=end"), nomatch = 0L]
result
#                arrayA              arrayB
#1: 2000-12-31 10:00:00 2000-12-31 10:00:00
#2: 2000-12-31 12:00:00 2000-12-31 12:00:01
```

Note that the non-equi join doesn't require to set keys beforehand thanks to auto-indexing.

#### Benchmarking

**TO DO:** Would be fun to compare `fuzzyjoin`, `foverlaps()`, and *non-equi join* on a large use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(fuzzyjoin)
arrayA<-c("2000-12-31 10:00:00","2000-12-31 12:00:00")
arrayB<-c("2000-12-31 10:00:00","2000-12-31 12:00:01")
arrayA <- strptime(arrayA, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
arrayB <- strptime(arrayB, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

# make data frames for join operations
A <- as.data.frame(arrayA)
B <- as.data.frame(arrayB)

# fuzzyjoin works by matching rows where a function applied
# to the column pairs is TRUE. Here the function is defined 
# inline, and uses lubridate durations.
fuzzy_join(A, B, 
           by=c("arrayA" = "arrayB"), 
           match_fun = function(x,y) {abs(x-y) <= duration(2, "seconds")})

# arrayA              arrayB
# 1 2000-12-31 10:00:00 2000-12-31 10:00:00
# 2 2000-12-31 12:00:00 2000-12-31 12:00:01
```